# Windows 10 pro and Linux Mint 18.1 Serena

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, usb, linux-mint

I am having such trouble out here. I have my laptop installed with Windows 10 professional in it. It was just upgraded a week ago from Windows 8.1 pro. And I have decided to make Linux Mint 18.1, Serena Version, to be my dual boot. However, I guess I messed up since I have installed the Linux Mint inside the system partition of the Windows OS. Now, after booting, Windows 10 isn't accessible anymore. And I tried to reinstall a new OS, but I can't. I keep on having these troubles...
1.) BOOTMGR is missing
2.) Operating System is Missing
3.) File Installation Data is Missing
I tried many times, but I really can't make it. I booted my USB Flash Drive right, and used many softwares for booting already, like Rufus, Unetbootin (Linux), and the built-in Bootable USB Stick maker of Linux Mint.

My Laptop's Specs are this...
Brand: Samsung
Model: NP-SF510
HDD: 500 GiB
RAM: 4 GiB
Processor: Intel Core i3
x64 bit

Please, I really need help. I am going to use this for the upcoming school report... PLEASE.

Comment: For future reference, I might suggest running Linux has a virtual machine within [Windows 10 Hyper-V](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2087-hyper-v-virtualization-setup-use-windows-10-a.html).  I have seen **so** many people post Super User questions regarding a wide variety problems with their Windows/Linux dual-boot configuration.  In contrast, I almost *never* see anyone have issues with their Linux VM running as a Windows 10 Hyper-V guest operating system.

Comment: But it gone so complicated now. I can't even change my OS anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on a similar instance. Custom PC with win 10, when I installed Serena 18.1 Mint I initially panicked when I couldn't find win10. I found a source that said to use command "update-grub" and it worked like a charm. Both my OS's are identified and running.